# Card game: If I draw four cards randomly and you draw six, what is the probability that my highest card is higher than your highest?

Tags: probability, extreme-value

As stated in the title, say if I draw randomly 4 cards and you draw 6 from the same deck, what is the probability that my highest card beats your highest card?

How will this change if we draw from different decks?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a home work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This simple question has a complicated answer.  The complications are due to two factors:

1. The cards are drawn without replacement.  (Each draw therefore changes the contents of the deck that are available for subsequent draws.)
2. A deck usually has multiple cards of each value, making a tie for the highest card possible.

Since complications are inevitable, let's address a reasonably broad generalization of this problem and then look at special cases.  In the generalization, a "deck" consists of a finite number of cards.  The cards have $m$ distinct "values" that can be ranked from lowest up to highest.  Let there be $n_i \ge 1$ of the values that are ranked $i$ (with $i=1$ the lowest and $i=m$ the highest).  One player draws $a\ge 0$ cards from the deck and a second player draws $b\ge 1$ cards.  What is the chance that the highest ranked card in the first player's hand is *strictly* greater in value than the highest ranked card in the second player's hand?  Let this event be called $W$: a "win" for the first player.

One way to figure this out begins by noting that the procedure is equivalent to drawing $a+b$ cards from the deck, taking the first $a$ out of those to be the first player's cards, and the remaining $b$ to be the second player's cards.  Among these cards let $j$ be the highest value and let $k \ge 1$ be the number of cards of that value.  The first player wins only when she holds all $k$ of those cards.  The number of ways in which those particular cards can be found among $a$ cards is $\binom{a}{k}$, while the number of ways of positioning those $k$ cards among all $a+b$ that were drawn is $\binom{a+b}{k}$.

Now the chance that $j$ is the highest value and there are $k$ such cards is the chance of selecting $k$ out of $n_j$ cards of value $j$ and selecting the remaining $a+b-k$ out of the lower $n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + n_{j-1} = N_{j-1}$ values.  Because there are $\binom{N_m}{a+b}$ equiprobable draws of the $a+b$ cards, the answer is

$$\Pr(W) = \frac{1}{\binom{N_m}{a+b}}\sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{k=1}^{n_j} \frac{\binom{a}{k}}{\binom{a+b}{k}}\binom{n_j}{k}\binom{N_{j-1}}{a+b-k}.$$

(In this expression, $N_0=0$ and any binomial coefficient whose top value is less than its bottom value, or whose bottom value is negative, is taken to be zero.)  It's a relatively efficient calculation, taking time proportional to the number of cards in the deck.  Because it involves binomial coefficients exclusively, it is amenable to asymptotic approximations for large values of $a$ and $b$.

---

In some cases you might want to modify the definition of a "win".  This is readily done: by interchanging the values of $a$ and $b$, the same formula calculates the chance that the second player wins outright.  The difference between $1$ and the sum of those two chances is the chance of a tie.  You may assign that chance of a tie to the players in any proportion you like.

---

In many conventional decks of playing cards $m=13$ and $n_i=4$ for $i=1, 2, \ldots, m$.  Let us therefore consider any deck in which all the $n_i$ are the same value, say $n$.  In this case $N_{j-1} = (j-1)n$ and the preceding formula simplifies slightly to

$$\Pr(W) = \frac{1}{\binom{m n}{a+b}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\binom{a}{k}}{\binom{a+b}{k}}\binom{n}{k}\sum_{j=1}^m  \binom{(j-1)n}{a+b-k}.$$

For instance, with $m=13$ and $n=4$ in a common 52 card deck of 13 ranks, $a=4$, and $b=6$, $\Pr(W) = \frac{12297518}{38720339}\approx 0.3176$.  A simulation of 100,000 plays of this game produced an estimate of $0.3159$, which is precise to almost three significant figures and not significantly different from what the formula states.

---

The following `R` code is easily modified to estimate $\Pr(W)$ for any deck: simply change `a`, `b`, and `deck`.  It has been set to run only 10,000 plays, which should take less than a second to execute and is good for two significant figures in the estimate.

```R
a <- 4
b <- 6
deck <- rep(1:13, 4)
set.seed(17)
cards <- replicate(1e4, sample(deck, a+b))
win <- apply(cards, 2, function(x) max(x[1:a]) > max(x[-(1:a)]))
m <- mean(win)
se <- sqrt(m*(1-m)/length(win))
cat("Estimated Pr(a wins) =", round(m, 4), "+/-", round(se, 5), "\n")
```

The output in this instance is

> Estimated Pr(a wins) = 0.3132 +/- 0.00464

Comment: great answer! Can I ask what you think if each player draws from a different deck -- will this change the answer？

Comment: Yes, it will change the answer because what one person draws will be independent of what the other player draws.  In some ways that is an easier question, because the answer is a straightforward calculation of the chance that one random variable exceeds the value of another that is independent of it.

Comment: Note that, if there *weren't* any ties, the answer would trivially be $\frac{a}{a+b}$: out of the $a+b$ cards drawn, one must be highest, and its chance of ending up in the first player's hand is $a$ out of $a+b$. But as you note, the presence of multiple cards with the same value in the deck complicates things.

Comment: @Ilmari That's right.  (And it's this insight that originally suggested the solution I presented.)  With no ties, $n_i=1$ always, the sum of $k$ goes away, and the fraction $\binom{a}{k}/\binom{a+b}{k} = \binom{a}{1}/\binom{a+b}{1} = a/(a+b)$ factors out, showing how the general formula reduces to this simple one.

Comment: `A deck usually has multiple cards of each value, making a tie for the highest card possible.` Depends on how you classify "same" cards. Do you consider an Ace and Ace? or is a Spade higher than a club? How you deal with suit ranking would have huge effects on this...

Comment: @WernerCD True, but that effect has been explained: if the suits have a ranking, then there are no ties, and so the formula reduces to what limari's comment describes.